# Changing the remote url of a repository in libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

How can we change the remote url of a repository?

```
using (var repository = new Repository(repositoryPath))
{
    //Change the remote url first
    //Then checkout 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can we change the remote url of a repository?

```
var newUrl = "https://github.com/owner/my_repository.git";";

Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes[name];

// This will update the remote configuration, persist it
// and return a new instance of the updated remote

Remote updatedremote = repo.Network.Remotes.Update(remote, r => r.Url = newUrl);
```

For what it's worth, most of the remote properties can be updated by following the same pattern. Feel free to take a peek at the **[RemoteFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RepositoryFixture.cs)** test suite for more detailed examples.

Answer (score 2):

They had made **public virtual Remote Update(Remote remote, params Action[] actions)** obsolete.

```
var newUrl = "https://github.com/owner/my_repository.git";
WorkingRepository.Network.Remotes.Update("origin", r => { r.Url = uri; });
```